# Google Schema Bug - Wrong Suburb from Postcode

Tags: google-schemas

This looks like a bug, the schema returned address is to the suburb of "Petersham" rather than "Strathfield" on the postcode "2135".

Please advice what you recommend to fix the problem

[Returned Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n34VN.jpg)

[Provided Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3whU.png)

Comment: What's your expected outcome?

Comment: It should report "Strathfield" not "Petersham" as the suburb.